# Using lfind to retrieve the index of an element

Tags: c

With an array of a certain type of element. Is there a way to use lfind to retrieve the index of an element instead of a pointer to the element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have that with the pointer.

Subtract the start of the array from the returned pointer - that's the index.

**Edit to explain more, just in case:**

When you declare an array

```
int foo[5];
```

`foo` without an index is a pointer to the first element

```
foo == &foo[0]
```

So if I have a pointer to an element in the array

```
int *p = &foo[4];
```

I can get the index with:

```
int index = p - foo;
```